# A row in a android TableLayout that stays always on top,

Tags: android, tablelayout

I want to make a *Tablelayout* that has one fixed row what scrolls only horizontal, but when I scroll the layout vertically it will always stay on top,
Can someone please give me an idea how to do that?
[image]

Comment: Did you manage to achieve this result?

Comment: no, can you help me?

Comment: I think this library might be useful:
https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders